Bell-Klyshko Inequality, slight mistakes?
In the Bell-type inequalities for general $n$-partite state, one type of the inequality is the by Bell-Klyshko, here I cite from this paper [https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9804045].
I basically tried to derive for simple case of $n=3$, to see how it generalize for any $n$.
In three partite case, each qubit has a choice between two observable, denoted as $(\vec{a}_i \cdot \vec{\sigma})$ and $(\vec{a}_i' \cdot \vec{\sigma})$, which is the pauli vectors. In the paper, the operator for $n$ qubits is defined recursively as:
$\mathcal{B}_n = \mathcal{B}_{n-1} \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_n \cdot \vec{\sigma}) + (\vec{a}_n' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) + \mathcal{B}_{n-1}' \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_n \cdot \vec{\sigma}) - (\vec{a}_n' \cdot \vec{\sigma}))$
For $n=3$, then we have the $\mathcal{B}_3 =  \mathcal{B}_{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) + (\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) + \mathcal{B}_{2}' \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) - (\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma}))$
where $\mathcal{B}_2 =  (\vec{a}_1 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_2 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) + (\vec{a}_2' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) + (\vec{a}_1' \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_2 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) - (\vec{a}_2' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) $
and $\mathcal{B}_2'$ is defined similarly, but exchanging each $a_j$ into $a_j'$ and vice versa. Now, I am trying to calculate the bound for $||\mathcal{B}_3^2||$, where according to the paper, it should be:
$\mathcal{B}_3^2 =  \mathcal{B}_2^2 \otimes \frac{1}{2} ( 1+ \vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{a}_3')\mathbb{I} + \mathcal{B}_2'^2 \otimes \frac{1}{2} ( 1 - \vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{a}_3')\mathbb{I} + [\mathcal{B}_2,\mathcal{B}_2'] \otimes \frac{1}{2}i (\vec{a}_3 \times \vec{a}_3') \cdot \vec{\sigma}$
I got the first two parts by calculating them as follows. I defined $A = (\mathcal{B}_{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) + (\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) )$ and $B = (\mathcal{B}_{2}' \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) - (\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) )$. Then I obtain:
$AA =  \mathcal{B}_2^2 \otimes \frac{1}{2} ( 1+ \vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{a}_3')\mathbb{I}$
$BB =  \mathcal{B}_2'^2 \otimes \frac{1}{2} ( 1 - \vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{a}_3')\mathbb{I}$.
For the last terms, I assume they must be from $AB + BA$, which I obtained as follows.
$AB = (\mathcal{B}_{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) + (\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) )  (\mathcal{B}_{2}' \otimes \frac{1}{2}((\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma}) - (\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma})) ) 
= \mathcal{B}_2\mathcal{B}_2' \otimes \frac{1}{4} (- (\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma})(\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma}) + (\vec{a}_3' \cdot \vec{\sigma})(\vec{a}_3 \cdot \vec{\sigma}))$,
since $(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma})^2 = \mathbb{I}$, so for same terms it cancels out. Calculating the left side, I get $-\frac{i}{2}i(\vec{a}_3 \times \vec{a}_3') \cdot \vec{\sigma}$. Hence we finally have:
$AB = \mathcal{B}_2\mathcal{B}_2' \otimes -\frac{i}{2}(\vec{a}_3 \times \vec{a}_3') \cdot \vec{\sigma}$. Similarly for $BA$, I got
$BA = \mathcal{B}_2'\mathcal{B}_2 \otimes \frac{i}{2}(\vec{a}_3 \times \vec{a}_3') \cdot \vec{\sigma}$
Then by summing $AB+BA$, my answer is slightly different with the paper, i.e.,
$AB+BA = [\mathcal{B}_2' , \mathcal{B}_2] \otimes \frac{i}{2}(\vec{a}_3 \times \vec{a}_3') \cdot \vec{\sigma} $. Although even if I use my case, the bound is the same as in the paper ($\leq 2^{n+1}$), I wonder if this is a slight error in the paper or perhaps my derivation is totally wrong and I got it correct by chance?
